# как сделать запрос на веб сервис с помощью apache camel

Tags: java, apache, soap, camel

Здраствуйте.  У меня есть файлик request.xml с таким содержимым:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://localhost:8080/webservices">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:deviceRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <devices>              
                <device id="1" value="123" date="2002-05-30T09:00:00"/>
                <device id="2" value="123" date="2004-05-30T09:00:00"/>
                <device id="3" value="123" date="2006-05-30T09:00:00"/>
                <device id="4" value="123" date="2008-05-30T09:00:00"/>
                <device id="5" value="123" date="2010-05-30T09:00:00"/>
         </devices>
      </web:deviceRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Мне нужно отправить запрос на веб сервис.
У меня все работает если я отправляю запрос на *обычной яве*.

```
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/ws";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call( /* содержимое файлика request.xml сконвертированное в SOAPMessage */ request  , url);
        System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:");
        soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
        soapConnection.close();
```

Выше приведенный код работает

---

Но мне нужно отправить содержимое посредством apache camel, я делаю так.

```
CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        // uploadfolder - папка где лежит request.xml
        from("file:uploadfolder").to("spring-ws:http://localhost:8080/ws");
    }
});
camelContext.start();
```

Вот Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-ws</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

При отправке через camel ничего не работает и пишется такое сообщение:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  o.s.ws.server.EndpointNotFound - No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope]

org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException:  [404]
```

Помогите понять чего он хочет. Ведь если на обычной яве все нормально отправляется, значит проблема не в веб сервисе ?

Answer (score 0):

В принципе чтобы отправить файл с уже готовым реквестом можно обойтись одним camel-http.

```
from("file:uploadfolder").convertBodyTo(String.class).removeHeaders("*").setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("POST")).setHeader("Content-Type", constant("text/xml;charset=UTF-8")).setHeader("SOAPAction", constant("")).to("http://localhost:8080/ws");
```